# Keep getting "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile" while dynamically allocating 2-D array in a class

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, netbeans, cygwin

I have been attempting to write this program where I am required to utilize dynamically allocated arrays to print out a 2d matrix. I am only to write the cpp files and not allowed to modify anything in the header files.

I keep getting an exception

> 0 [main] review2_cis17c_objectarray 4018 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to review2_cis17c_objectarray.exe.stackdump

I am relatively new to learning c++; after contemplating, I think something is wrong in my PlusTab.cpp, where I am trying to assign an allocated address to a constructor-defined array in a class. Can someone please help and let me know here I did wrong in the project? Thank you very much!

AbsRow.h:

```
class AbsRow {
    protected:
        int size;
        int *rowData;
    public:
        virtual int getSize()const = 0;
        virtual int getData(int)const = 0;
};
```

AbsTabl.h:

```
class AbsTabl {
    protected:
        int szRow;
        int szCol;
        RowAray **columns;
    public:
        virtual int getSzRow()const = 0;
        virtual int getSzCol()const = 0;
        virtual int getData(int,int)const = 0; };
```

PlusTab.h

```
class PlusTab:public Table {
    public:
        PlusTab(unsigned int r,unsigned int c):Table(r,c){};
        PlusTab operator+(const PlusTab &);
};
```

RowAray.h

```
class RowAray:public AbsRow {
    public:
        RowAray(unsigned int);
        virtual ~RowAray();
        int getSize()const{return size;}
        int getData(int i)const{
            if(i>=0&&i<size)return rowData[i];
            else return 0;}
        void setData(int,int);
};
```

Table.h

```
#include "AbsTabl.h"
class Table:public AbsTabl {
    public:
        Table(unsigned int,unsigned int);
        Table(const Table &);
        virtual ~Table();
        int getSzRow()const {return szRow;}
        int getSzCol()const {return szCol;}
        int getData(int,int)const;
        void setData(int,int,int);
};
```

PlusTab.cpp:

```
#include "PlusTab.h"

PlusTab PlusTab::operator+(const PlusTab &t) {
    PlusTab tab(this->getSzRow(), this->getSzCol());
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.getSzRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <tab.getSzCol(); j++) {
            (tab.columns[i])->setData(j, this->getData(i,j) + t.getData(i,j));
        }
    }
   
    return tab;
}
```

RowAray.cpp:

```
#include "RowAray.h"
        
RowAray::RowAray(unsigned int c) {
    size = c;
    
    rowData = new int[c];
}

RowAray::~RowAray() {
    delete []rowData;
}

void RowAray::setData(int i, int value) {
   rowData[i] = value;
}
```

Table.cpp:

```
#include "Table.h"
#include <cstdlib>
Table::Table(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) {
    
    szRow = r;
    szCol = c;

    columns = new RowAray*[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        columns[i] = new RowAray(c);
    }
        
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            columns[i]->setData(j, (rand()%90 + 10));
        }
    }
}

Table::~Table() {
    for (int i = 0; i < szRow; i++) {
        delete []columns[i];
    }
    delete []columns;
}

Table::Table(const Table &t) {
    szRow = t.szRow;
    szCol = t.szCol;
    columns = t.columns;
};
 
int Table::getData(int r ,int c) const {
    return columns[r]->getData(c);
};

void Table::setData(int r, int c, int value) {
    columns[r]->setData(c,value);
}
```

and finally my `main.cpp`, which I am not allowed to modify either.

```
 #include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//User Libraries
#include "PlusTab.h"

//Global Constants

//Function Prototype
void prntTab(const Table &);

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   //Initialize the random seed
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
   
   //Declare Variables
   int rows=3,cols=4;
   
   //Test out the Tables
   PlusTab tab1(rows,cols);
   PlusTab tab2(tab1);
   PlusTab tab3=tab1+tab2;
   
  // Print the tables
   cout<<"Abstracted and Polymorphic Print Table 1 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab1);
   cout<<"Copy Constructed Table 2 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab2);
   cout<<"Operator Overloaded Table 3 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab3);

   //Exit Stage Right
   return 0;
}

void prntTab(const Table &a){
    cout<<endl;
    for(int row=0;row<a.getSzRow();row++){
        for(int col=0;col<a.getSzCol();col++){
            cout<<setw(4)<<a.getData(row,col);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I apologize for this massive amount of code. This is my first time posting, will learn to use the website! I appreciate your help:)

Comment: Is the `enter code here` correct ?

Comment: please recheck your code, as it does not compile as it is.

Comment: Sorry. I will change my codes immediately.

Comment: Are you using a Makefile? If so add `-g` to the C++ options where you compile the program, else add `-g` to the compiler command line. Then run your program under `gdb`. You may need to run cygwin's setup again to install the `gdb` debugging program. Start your program with `gdb  review2_cis17c_objectarray.exe`. At the the `(gdb)` prompt enter `run`. When the crash happens you should drop into `gdb` here you can enter commands to see where you are in the program. Use the `help command first. Hint, `list` shows your code. HTH.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: Now I think it is to do with me using one of the "delete" keys wrong. Couldn't spot it out... Changing gbd did not help.